# Using Google map with navigation drawer and viewpager crashes

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm using google map fragment inside a viewpager and this viewpager is a part of navigation drawer's fragments. Now when i start this my application it works fine, but when i change the  navdrawer item and then come back to this map fragment, the application crashes with this error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
```

I have tried everything and search whole day on this but couldn't find any proper solution for this error.

now this is my code:

MapFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
    }

    try {
        view = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_mapview, container, false);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    initialize(view);
    return view;
}

public void setUpMapIfNeeded() {


    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) this.getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

}
```

activity_mapview.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I belive your problem is that your program tries to create a new fragment with the same ID, each time you choose your map fragment. To solve this, your map needs to get the value NULL.

Try to paste this in your class MapFragment:

```
    @Override
public void onDestroyView() {

    SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    if (f != null) {
        try {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Below onCreateView. This worked for me, and probably will for you to.